# Are there any restrictions to the number of weapons a survivor can equip?

Tags: dead-of-winter

In the game, Dead of Winter, one of the players had their survivor pretty much camp out at the police station and search for weapons.

He then equipped pretty much every single weapon he found to the same survivor, including weapons that were already equipped (i.e. 2 identical handguns etc).

It seemed a bit overpowered, but I couldn't find any restriction on the number of items a survivor can equip. Has anyone come across any other ruling on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are no limits to the number of weapons that a survivor can equip and the effects stack. This has been confirmed in the Dead of Winter Rules forum on BoardGameGeek by Jon Gilmour, one of the designers of Dead of Winter.

Click [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/16579575#16579575) to read one of these threads (Jon Gilmour's responses are posted under the user name JonnyRotten).

A second thread reference can be found [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1216317/can-you-equip-more-same-item-type).